# PostgreSQL generate_series strange behaviour

Tags: postgresql, explain, generate-series

The two following queries produce the exact same output:

```sql
select
  ref_date::date
from generate_series('2020-10-01', '2020-10-01'::date, interval '1 day') ref_date
--   ref_date
-- 2020-10-01

select now()::date ref_date
--   ref_date
-- 2020-10-01
```

However, when running `explain` on each of them, we get different things:

```
# query 1
Function Scan on generate_series ref_date  (cost=0.01..12.51 rows=1000 width=4)

# query 2
Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4)
```

Things get worse when including one or the other in a sequence of joins, with joining conditions based on `ref_date`:

```sql
select
  stuff
from (select ref_date::date from generate_series('2020-10-01', '2020-10-01'::date, interval '1 day') ref_date) ref_date
left join (other_stuff) x on true
left join (more_stuff) y on y.id = x.id and y.timestamp < ref_date
-- executes in 10 minutes
-- EXPLAIN is long and complex
-- query uses index on more_stuff.(id) only
   despite an index on (id, timestamp) being available

select
  stuff
from (select now()::date ref_date) ref_date
left join (other_stuff) x on true
left join (more_stuff) y on y.id = x.id and y.timestamp < ref_date
-- executes in ten milliseconds
-- EXPLAIN is short and simple
-- query adequately uses index on more_stuff.(id, timestamp)
```

The reason I can't use `now()::date` in reality is that I need the `generate_series()` to generate multiple dates (like, spanning 5 years).

**Question**:

Is there a way to use an alternative method which uses a sequence of dates and is as efficient as when using `now()::date` in the above examples?

Notes:

- the `generate_series()` method performs much worse than `now()::date` **even when only one date is generated**
- using a pre-constructed table with the output of generate_series (instead of using generate_series directly in the query) produces the same results as using the function directly, even with an index on this table
- the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output for both versions (now() and generate_series()) can be found here: https://gist.github.com/JivanRoquet/a4f1c82ecf54b420844e652584317c76

Comment: How do you know that generate_series is slower? Are you basing this just on the cost in the EXPLAIN? (Don't do that; the cost is a unitless number used by the planner to pick among plans, and it has no meaningful translation to wall-clock seconds, CPU seconds, or, well, anything.) edit: sorry for the comment spam, I didn't read closely enough, you are indeed measuring wall-clock times :)

Comment: @AdamKG I know because I've actually executed the queries listed in the last examples (albeit adapted to make them real). One takes 10ms, the other 10 minutes. For real. — edit: ok, just saw your own edit :)

Comment: You need to show us the execution plan for the query which has the problem, not some different query which doesn't.

Comment: @jjanes you're absolutely right, here are the EXPLAIN ANALYZE outputs https://gist.github.com/JivanRoquet/a4f1c82ecf54b420844e652584317c76

Comment: I _think_ it's related to the poor row estimation for `generate_series()` rather than the overhead of the function itself. While there is an overhead in calling the function, it doesn't justify the difference you see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=644eb889f771eae77035ecd2f99a487b

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery can do what you're asking.

```
select stuff
FROM generate_series('2020-09-01'::date, '2020-10-01'::date, interval '1 day') as ref_date
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(select (other_stuff)) AS x on true
left join (more_stuff) y on y.timestamp < ref_date
```

This should generate a nested loop join, with the plan for the inner part matching your fast query. The LATERAL keyword forces the database to freshly evaluate the right-hand-side for each row in the left-hand-side.

Comment: Are you purposefully doing the `left join lateral` on `select (other_stuff)` only? Or did you mean to englobe the whole rest of the query into it? I just tested the former and it didn't change the performance (still bad with generate_series).

Comment: Update, after trying to encapsulate the whole right-hand-side of the query (after the `lateral` keyword) into the `left join lateral`, the performances remain identical (good with `now()` and poor with generate_series)

Comment: Yeah, lateral shouldn't make a difference for the 2nd left join; the presence of ref_date in the join condition should have already done what LATERAL does. This points to it being a legitimately bad guess by the planner for something, probably how correlated more_stuff.id and more_stuff.timestamp are, but we'd need to see the EXPLAINs to tell for sure. Take a look at [extended statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html), but I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with them.

Comment: Interesting. I've just created a gist with the two EXPLAIN outputs of the real queries: https://gist.github.com/JivanRoquet/a4f1c82ecf54b420844e652584317c76

Comment: An EXPLAIN ANALYZE would be helpful; the important part is where the actual vs estimated row count differs.

Comment: I've included the EXPLAIN ANALYZE in the same gist (below the EXPLAINs), after restricting the queries' scope so that the longer ones takes less than 10 minutes. As you can see the fast one took 0.7ms while the long one took 48s.

Comment: The most staggering difference I can see is the most-nested index scans (at the bottom), one (slow) is showing `(actual time=0.024..23970.600 rows=126960 loops=2)` while the other (fast) is showing `(actual time=0.215..0.287 rows=86 loops=2)`. Looks like many, many more rows are considered by the slower query.

Comment: Still looking at the EXPLAINs, but one quick thing to try is to stick an OFFSET 0 into either/both of the joined subqueries, if they don't already have a LIMIT. Not sure if it'll help here, just forces the planner to exclude certain plans. (Incidentally, the EXPLAINs and the EXPLAIN ANALYZEs don't seem to be for the same query - the EXPLAIN ANALYZEs have no limit nodes, which do appear in the first two - so I'm just assuming the ANALYZE ones are the ones I want)

Comment: "the EXPLAIN ANALYZEs have no limit nodes, which do appear in the first two" -> this is correct, I just manually entered some values to keep the count low for these ones, while I was querying yet-another-table with a limit for the EXPLAIN versions. The correct version should indeed be the ANALYZE ones.